# Definition calculating incorrectly?

Tags: python, dataframe, function

I have a dataframe with fractions.

It should return the float value of that fraction.

```
df:
   Unnamed: 0  country      league home_odds draw_odds away_odds             datetime      home_team           away_team  home_score  away_score
0      381084  Iceland  League Cup    167/50   329/100    63/100  2016-02-16 19:15:00      Kopavogur  Vikingur Reykjavik           0           1
1      381085  Iceland  League Cup   463/100    173/50    47/100  2016-02-14 21:15:00           Fram            Stjarnan           0           3
2      381086  Iceland  League Cup      9/25     99/25    303/50  2016-02-14 19:15:00   KR Reykjavik              Haukar           1           1
3      381087  Iceland  League Cup      9/25   393/100   611/100  2016-02-14 19:00:00  Thor Akureyri          Leiknir F.           5           0
4      381088  Iceland  League Cup     11/25   353/100    251/50  2016-02-14 17:00:00        Akranes           Grindavik           5           0
```

I am using:

```
def convert(s):
    if '/' in str(s):  # is a fraction
        num, den = s.split('/')
        return 1 + int(num) / int(den)
    else:
        return float(s)

odds_cols = ['home_odds', 'draw_odds', 'away_odds']

df[odds_cols] = df[odds_cols].applymap(convert)
```

White it returns

```
   Unnamed: 0  country      league  home_odds  draw_odds  away_odds             datetime      home_team           away_team  home_score  away_score
0      381084  Iceland  League Cup       3.34       3.29       0.63  2016-02-16 19:15:00      Kopavogur  Vikingur Reykjavik           0           1
1      381085  Iceland  League Cup       4.63       3.46       0.47  2016-02-14 21:15:00           Fram            Stjarnan           0           3
2      381086  Iceland  League Cup       0.36       3.96       6.06  2016-02-14 19:15:00   KR Reykjavik              Haukar           1           1
3      381087  Iceland  League Cup       0.36       3.93       6.11  2016-02-14 19:00:00  Thor Akureyri          Leiknir F.           5           0
4      381088  Iceland  League Cup       0.44       3.53       5.02  2016-02-14 17:00:00        Akranes           Grindavik           5           0
```

It should return

```
   Unnamed: 0  country      league  home_odds  draw_odds  away_odds             datetime      home_team           away_team  home_score  away_score
0      381084  Iceland  League Cup       4.34       4.29       1.63  2016-02-16 19:15:00      Kopavogur  Vikingur Reykjavik           0           1
1      381085  Iceland  League Cup       5.63       4.46       1.47  2016-02-14 21:15:00           Fram            Stjarnan           0           3
2      381086  Iceland  League Cup       1.36       4.96       7.06  2016-02-14 19:15:00   KR Reykjavik              Haukar           1           1
3      381087  Iceland  League Cup       1.36       4.93       7.11  2016-02-14 19:00:00  Thor Akureyri          Leiknir F.           5           0
4      381088  Iceland  League Cup       1.44       4.53       6.02  2016-02-14 17:00:00        Akranes           Grindavik           5           0
```

Since odds_cols have float and int values too, I cannot just apply `return 1 + float(s)`

What is the correct way to return the values as desired?

Also, when I type

```
print(df.dtypes)


Unnamed: 0      int64
country        object
league         object
home_odds     float64
draw_odds     float64
away_odds     float64
datetime       object
home_team      object
away_team      object
home_score      int64
away_score      int64
dtype: object
```

How come pandas identifies the value `167/50` as float?

Answer (score 2):

If the data in home_odds, draw_odds and away_odds is as shown in the strings format then I get exactly what you want from your exact function.

I'd test casting the odds_cols to strings e.g.

```
df['home_odds'] = df['home_odds'].astype(str)
```

and see the output.

Answer (score 1):

your function likely doesn't get executed on the condition to catch the fraction

```
def convert(s):
    if '/' in str(s):  # is a fraction
        # TRY ADDING a print statement here 
        num, den = s.split('/')
        return 1 + int(num) / int(den)
    else:
        return float(s)
```

Likely you always get the `float(s)` execution path, all because the frame keeps the numbers, not strings.

Comment: I dont understand. What should I add in the print statement?

Comment: add `print(type(s))` to see which type is `s`

Comment: It returns `None` when I `print(type(s))` What does that mean?

Comment: means it is a `None` value